# Qt.binding in a for loop

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

In a `TabView`, I'm trying to load a list of `Tab` items from a string property:

```
TabView {
    id: tabView1
    property string tabs: "/etc,/bin"

    function loadTabs() {
        var tab_array = tabs.split(",");
        for (var i = 0; i < tab_array.length; i ++) {
            var dirTableView = Qt.createComponent("dirview.qml");

            var newTab = tabView1.addTab("", dirTableView);
            newTab.active = true;
            newTab.item.folderUrl = "file://" + tab_array[i];
            newTab.title = Qt.binding(function() {
                return newTab.item.folderUrl.toString().replace("file://", "");
            });
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted: {
        loadTabs();
    }
}
```

Each `Tab` loads a `TableView` of directory content (as specified in `dirview.qml`).

The `Tab.title` binding doesn't work, because `newTab` gets reassigned to a different `Tab` in each iteration, hence the result is that all the tabs' title is bound to the title of the *last* tab.

I tried to use an array to store different `Tab` items returned by `TabView.addTab()`:

```
property var tabArray: []

function loadTabs() {
    var tab_array = tabs.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < tab_array.length; i ++) {
        var dirTableView = Qt.createComponent("dirview.qml");
        tabArray[i] = tabView1.addTab("", dirTableView);
        tabArray[i].active = true;
        tabArray[i].item.folderUrl = "file://" + tab_array[i];
        tabArray[i].title = Qt.binding(function() {
            return tabArray[i].item.folderUrl.toString().replace("file://", "");
        });
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work either. Apparently `Qt.binding()` is triggered as soon as the array is declared, but at that time, the array is empty, hence I get the error "Cannot read property 'item' of undefined" (referring to `Qt.binding()`). Strangely, somehow the titles are correctly set when the application starts, but when `item.folderUrl` changes as I navigate around the directory tree, the title doesn't update accordingly, hence the binding isn't working.

What is the way to do `Qt.binding` correctly in a for loop here?

Answer (score 1):

Just tried one more little thing and it worked!

```
function loadTabs() {
    var tab_array = tabs.split(",");
    for (var i = 0; i < tab_array.length; i ++) {
        var dirTableView = Qt.createComponent("dirview.qml");
        var newTab = tabView1.addTab("", dirTableView);
        newTab.active = true;
        newTab.item.folderUrl = "file://" + tab_array[i];
        newTab.title = Qt.binding(function() {
            return this.item.folderUrl.toString().replace("file://", "");
        });
    }
}
```

The only change made is that in the binding expression, `newTab` is replaced by `this`. Inspired by [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html).

Apparently using `this` eliminates the ambiguity, `Qt.binding()` knows exactly which `newTab` to refer to.

Comment: There is no ambiguity, its JS weird scoping rules. There aren't `tab_array.length` number of `newTab`s, there is only one and all expressions reference it, and it is stuck on the last value it had.